# Property implementation - Noob lacks knowledge

Tags: c#, properties

I’m sure this has been answered before sorry, but I can’t condense my question to a googlable phrase.

I have a Pt3 class which is a 3d Cartesian point (x, y, z properties plus a few other goodies).  I use the Pt3 type as get/set property values in a RegionProvider class - for Location and Normal.

The Location property is fine, I don’t care how the property is set:

```
//Location set method 1 - sweet...
RegionProvider Foo = new RegionProvider();
Foo.Location.x = 10;
Foo.Location.y = 20;
Foo.Location.z = 30;

//Location set method 2 - also sweet...
RegionProvider Foo2 = new RegionProvider();
Foo2.Location = new Pt3(10, 20, 30);
```

The Normal property needs different behavior though.  I want the RegionProvider class to normalize input to Normal property if required  e.g. if the caller set the “normal” value to 40,50,60 the RegionProvider class would normalize to 0.4558, 0.5698, 0.6838 (to give a vector length == 1).  If the caller does the following, everything is cool...

```
//Normal set method A - sweet...
Foo.Normal = new Pt3(40, 50, 60);
```

...but if grief will ensue if they do this:

```
//Normal set method B - grief...
Foo2.Normal.x = 40;
Foo2.Normal.y = 50;
Foo2.Normal.z = 60;
```

...because the RegionProvider class will normalize as each element is set.  What I want to do is prevent callers from seeing the x, y, z of the Normal property so they are forced to use method 'A' above.

One solution could be to not normalize the property set at all, but normalize the property get but this seems like fakery.

For what it's worth, here's my Normal property declaration:

```
/// <summary>
/// Property for the objects normal
/// </summary>
public Pt3 Normal
{
    set
    {
        _normal = Bit555ModelCore.NormalizeVector(value);
        this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Normal");
    }
    get
    {
        return _normal;
    }
}
```

Cheers in advance for any help....

Comment: Standard .NET trap, never the same way, always the same problem.  The Normal property is a value type, you get a copy when you access it.  You'll update the copy, not the original.  The boilerplate wisdom is "don't mutate a struct".

Comment: @HansPassant I don't think this question is about `struct`s. It's about disallowing setting properties of a property independently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have two options:

1. Make sure that the properties of `Pt3` are never set independently by making the whole class immutable:

   ```
   class Pt3
   {
       public Pt3(double x, double y, double z)
       {
           X = x;
           Y = y;
           Z = z;
       }

       public double X { get; private set; }
       public double Y { get; private set; }
       public double Z { get; private set; }
   }
   ```
2. Have two classes: `Pt3Mutable` and `Pt3Immutable` (or some better names).  `Pt3Immutable` would be immutable, so you could use it for `Normal` safely. `Pt3Mutable` would be mutable, so if you used it for `Location`, method 1 would still work.

   You could then have cast operators to convert between the two types: implicit cast from `Pt3Mutable` to `Pt3Immutable` and explicit cast the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

If Pt3 is your class, remove the setters, (X, Y, Z) or make them private.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Normal` and `Location` have to be of the same type, Pt3 could have simple property:

```
public bool CanSetXyz { get; }
```

For `Location`, initialize this property to `true`. For `Normal`, initialize it to `false`.

Then in each X, Y, and Z property:

```
private int _x;

public int X
{
    get { return _x; }
    set
    {
        if (!CanSetXyz)
        {
            throw new CantSetXyzException("Can't set X on a Normal point.");
        }
        _x = value;
    }
}
```

If they do not have to be the same type, you'd want to make a common base class with the things that are always shared between the two, and then one class would have no setters for X, Y, and Z, and the other would have public setters.

Example:

```
public abstract class BasePt3
{
    protected int x;
}

public class LocationPt3 : BasePt3
{
    public int X
    {
        get { return x; }
        set { x = value; }
    }

    public LocationPt3(int _x)
    {
        x = _x;
    }
}

public class NormalPt3 : BasePt3
{
    public int X
    {
        get { return x; }
    }

    public NormalPt3(int _x)
    {
        x = _x;
    }
}
```

EDIT: A perhaps more useful example, with the base class allowing X to be read:

```
public abstract class BasePt3
{
    protected int x;

    public int X
    {
        get { return x; }
    }
}

public class LocationPt3 : BasePt3
{
    public new int X
    {
        get { return x; }
        set { x = value; }
    }

    public LocationPt3(int _x)
    {
        x = _x;
    }
}

public class NormalPt3 : BasePt3
{
    public new int X
    {
        get { return x; }
    }

    public NormalPt3(int _x)
    {
        x = _x;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Pt3` should probably be a struct and treated as an immutable value.

Remove the setters and only allow setting of the coordinates through the constructor. A user of your type will then not be able to change one property at a time and `RegionProvider` will always know when the value of `Normal` has changed.

This is pretty much how [System.Drawing.Point](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.point.aspx) behaves, except that `Point` allows X and Y to be set causing all sorts of problems when people try things like

```
Foo.Bar.X += 10;
```

instead of

```
Foo.Bar += new Size(10, 0);
```

Comment: I think it should be a struct because I would expect a type representing a point to behave like a value, being immutable and passed by copy. I may be influenced by the BCL defining Point and related types as structs.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the problem lies in your statement about 'goodies'.

If you decided that you want to have a vector class (your Pt3), use it as such.  Define 'Normalize()' method and use it explicitly.

Well, that would be my advice, anyway.